# C# async method call with or without await call gives same result?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, join, async-await

I have a simple program to test async/await, 2 versions: version 1 awaits another method inside async function, version doesn't:

Program 1:

```
 class Program 
 { 
     static void Main(string[] args) 
     { 
         Console.WriteLine("main starts.."); 
         AsyncMethod(); 
         Thread.Sleep(1000); 
         Console.WriteLine("main ends.."); 
         Console.ReadLine(); 
     } 
     static async void AsyncMethod() 
     { 
         Console.WriteLine("async starts"); 
         var result = await MyMethod(); 
         Console.WriteLine("async starts ends"); 
     } 

     static async Task<int> MyMethod() 
     { 
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
         { 
             Console.WriteLine("async runs" + i.ToString() + ".."); 
             await Task.Delay(1000); 
         } 
         return 0; 
     } 
 }
```

Program 2:

```
 class Program 
 { 
     static void Main(string[] args) 
     { 
         Console.WriteLine("main starts.."); 
         AsyncMethod(); 
         Thread.Sleep(1000); 
         Console.WriteLine("main ends.."); 
         Console.ReadLine(); 
     } 
     static async void AsyncMethod() 
     { 
         Console.WriteLine("async starts"); 
         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
         { 
             Console.WriteLine("async runs" + i.ToString() + ".."); 
             await Task.Delay(1000); 
         } 
         Console.WriteLine("async ends"); 
     } 
 }
```

Both programs yields same result. I am just curious, do both program differs in what happens in the background?

1. I guess, program 1 will create 2 sub-threads, each level of "async" leads to a thread; program 2 will create 1 sub-thread. Right?
2. As long as "await" will wait until the task ends, then what's the difference from writing synchronous code? I think it just link creating several threads and call ".join()" for all of them. Right?

Comment: Be careful there are no threads...https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: There are several problems with this code: (1) Why are you using Thread.Sleep? (2) Why is your Main method not async? (3) Why are you calling AsyncMethod() without a continuation or exception handler? (4) Async does not mean threads

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: (5) do not use "async void" except in handlers (use "usync Task" instead)

Comment: If not using Thread.sleep, then what kind of sleep should I use?

Comment: async code should use [`await Task.Delay(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are async or Threaded programming using await means until your function execute your execution pointer will be hold on that functions it self and if you don't use wait it will pass on to next execution pointer mostly there is two reason behind adding await mostly in winform application while going for big process execution we may need to let software user to do the other work in the same form then we need to await the task. or some times we need get some data from one method so the method should be finished and next logic should execute in a new or other thread.